# Convert phone number to international E.164 format for database usage

Tags: php, regex, phone-number, libphonenumber

Via an online form I get phone numbers in various formats like

```
0123456789
+49 123456789
+49123456789
00123456789
0049 123456789
```

Right now I format them via PHP RegEx using a very simple way, as I only accept german numbers:

```php
$phonenumber = "+49".preg_replace(array('/^(?:00490?|0490?|\+490?|0)?/','/\D/'),array('',''),$phonenumber);
```

Now some other European countries shall be added, so I need to grep the two digits country code that follows the "+" or "00" characters.

What's the best way to implement this? I tried RegEx `^\+(\d){2}`, but it's also selecting the plus sign. Further I know about the Google libphonenumber library. However, that would be too much for now as all the numbers I need have a 2-digits country code, no +1 for US or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In Europe [most country calling codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Europe) start with 3 or 4. Some of those have three digits. For coping with those country codes you could do this:

```
$phonenumber = preg_replace(['/\D/', '/^0(?!0)/', '/^\+?0*((3[578]?|42?)\d)0*/'], 
                            ['',     '+49',       '+$1'], $phonenumber);
```

This has three steps:

1. Remove non digits
2. Add the default country code when the number starts with 0 and then a non-zero, i.e. a local number
3. Detect the country code and remove any zeroes immediately surrounding that country code, and (re)insert the `+`.